# How parsing out XML file with namespaces?

Tags: php, xml, object, xpath, simplexml

I know similar questions were posted before, but I can't parse out this XML file with namespaces.

Here is the link to it because it's too big to post here: https://tsdrapi.uspto.gov/ts/cd/casestatus/sn86553893/info.xml

I tried using `simplexml_load_file` but that does not create xml object. Then I found similar problems and try something like this, provided I already downloaded file named it 86553893.xml

Here is my php code:

```
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement("86553893.xml");
                            foreach($xml->xpath('//com:ApplicationNumber') as $event) {
                                var_export($event->xpath('com:ApplicationNumberText'));
                        }
```

Comment: you got some advance?

Comment: [SimpleXML cannot handle namespaces properly](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xpathphp/), use `DOMXPath`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to register the namespaces on each element you want to use them:

```
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement("86553893.xml");
$xml->registerXpathNamespace('com', 'http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/Common/1');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//com:ApplicationNumber') as $event) {
  $event->registerXpathNamespace(
    'com', 'http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/Common/1'
  );                         
  var_export($event->xpath('com:ApplicationNumberText'));
}
```

This is different in DOM, you use an DOMXPath instance, so it is only a single object and you will have to register the namespaces only once.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("86553893.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('com', 'http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/Common/1');

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//com:ApplicationNumber') as $event) {
  var_export($xpath->evaluate('string(com:ApplicationNumberText)', $event));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass the 3th param as `true`:

```
<?php

$xml= new SimpleXMLElement("info.xml", NULL, true);
                            foreach($xml->xpath('//com:ApplicationNumber') as $event) {
                                    var_export($event->xpath('com:ApplicationNumberText'));

}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
  )),
)
```

you can read more about `SimpleXMLElement` in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php