# Retrieving an array of values from an XML content with multiple namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I posted another question, which to my error was incomplete.
I have an XML with multiple namespaces, but I need to access the values of  in a foreach.

My XML array is:

```
<ArrayOfSession xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1'> 
<Session>
  <AreComplimentariesAllowed>true</AreComplimentariesAllowed>
  <Attributes xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d3p1:string>0000000009</d3p1:string>
    <d3p1:string>0000000011</d3p1:string>
  </Attributes>
</Session>
</ArrayOfSession>
```

I was helped by another user at: [Retrieving an array of values from an XML content with a namespace in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40724604/retrieving-an-array-of-values-from-an-xml-content-with-a-namespace-in-php#40724977)

With that answer I have tried a few variations. This being my current one, which isn't working:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('j', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');

foreach($xml->xpath('//ns:d3p1') as $header){
    var_export($header->xpath('//Attributes/ns:string'));
}
```

I also tried:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//ns:d3p1') as $header){
        var_export($header->xpath('//ns:string'));
    }
```

This is stumping me!

In my current working version for the rest of code, I'm retrieving the elements with:

```
foreach($xml->Session as $event){
    // Do Something with $event->AreComplimentariesAllowed
}
```

This works fine, but I just can't access those Attributes elements.

Thanks as ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the namespaces it on each `SimpleXMLElement` before you call `xpath()`. You register them on the `$xml` variable, but not on `$header`.

Your XML has an default namespace, too. You do register the prefix `j` for it, but you do not use the prefix in the expressions. Last here are no elements `d3p1`. This is only a namespace prefix in the document.

So to iterate the `Session` elements and then the `string` values inside the `Attributes`

```
$sessions = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sessions->registerXPathNamespace(
  'j', 
  'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1'
);

foreach($sessions->xpath('//j:Session') as $session) {
  $session->registerXPathNamespace(
    'j', 
    'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1'
  );
  $session->registerXPathNamespace(
    'ns', 
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
  );
  var_export($session->xpath('.//j:Attributes/ns:string'));
}
```

In DOM this looks different:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace(
  'j', 
  'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1'
);
$xpath->registerNamespace(
  'ns', 
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'
);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//j:Session') as $session) {
  var_export(
    iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('.//j:Attributes/ns:string', $session))
  );
}
```

It has a dedicated Xpath object, so the namespace registration has to be done only once.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm still a little confused. Is this not registering them first? `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('j', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');`

Comment: Only on the SimpleXMLElement represented by the `$xml` variable, but you call the method on the $header variable. In SimpleXML you will have to register the namespaces again and again on each variable. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29556930/2265374

Comment: Thanks. I can see the relationship, but can't piece it together: https://eval.in/683080

Comment: I rewrote my answer, you missed the default namespace.

Comment: Perfect. I can see where I went wrong and what I need to reference at which point. It goes without saying that I appreciate the time you've taken to guide me through it - thanks.